# Atualizar quantidade de item em tabela

Tags: vue.js, front-end

Pessoal estou iniciando com Vue e estou com uma pequena dificuldade.
Na imagem abaixo eu tenho uma tabela com alguns itens e quando eu vou aumentar a quantidade do item Laranja por exemplo é aumentado todos os demais itens, como corrigido isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo meu código

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
        return {
            quantidade: 1,
            Opcionais: [
                { Code: 1, Nome: 'Abacaxi', Valor: "50.00" },
                { Code: 2, Nome: 'Abacate', Valor: "50.00" },
                { Code: 3, Nome: 'Morango', Valor: "60.00" },
                { Code: 4, Nome: 'Maçã', Valor: "17.00" },
                { Code: 5, Nome: 'Laranja', Valor: "30.00" }
            ]
        }
    },

    methods: {
      adicionar() {
          this.quantidade++
      },
      
      remover() {
          if(this.quantidade === 0) {
              this.quantidade = 0
          } else {
              this.quantidade--
          }
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template>
    <div class="usuario-lista">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#Code</th>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Valor</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(opcional, row) in Opcionais" :key="opcional.Code">
                    <td>
                        <button @click="remover">-</button>
                        <input type="text" :value="quantidade">
                        <button @click="adicionar(row)">+</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ opcional.Nome }}</td>
                    <td>{{ opcional.Valor }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma opção é colocar a quantidade como uma `chave` em cada `objeto`.

Aí é só aumentar/diminuir no clique. Se for só isso, nem precisa criar um `método`.

Exemplo (adicionei uma coluna com o valor * quantidade):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
        return {
            quantidade: 1,
            Opcionais: [
                { Code: 1, Nome: 'Abacaxi', Valor: "50.00", Qtd: 0 },
                { Code: 2, Nome: 'Abacate', Valor: "50.00", Qtd: 0 },
                { Code: 3, Nome: 'Morango', Valor: "60.00", Qtd: 0 },
                { Code: 4, Nome: 'Maçã', Valor: "17.00", Qtd: 0 },
                { Code: 5, Nome: 'Laranja', Valor: "30.00", Qtd: 0 }
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template>
    <div class="usuario-lista">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#Code</th>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Valor Unitário</th>
                    <th>Valor Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="(opcional, row) in Opcionais" :key="opcional.Code">
                    <td>
                        <button @click="opcional.Qtd ? opcional.Qtd-- : false">-</button>
                        <input type="text" :value="opcional.Qtd">
                        <button @click="opcional.Qtd++">+</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ opcional.Nome }}</td>
                    <td>{{ opcional.Valor }}</td>
                    <td>{{ opcional.Valor * opcional.Qtd }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do `data(){return{}}` ficam declaradas as variáveis que está utilizando.
No seu caso, apenas uma variável está declarada, `quantidade: 1`

```
data() {
        return {
            quantidade: 1,
            Opcionais: [
                { Code: 1, Nome: 'Abacaxi', Valor: "50.00" },
                { Code: 2, Nome: 'Abacate', Valor: "50.00" },
                { Code: 3, Nome: 'Morango', Valor: "60.00" },
                { Code: 4, Nome: 'Maçã', Valor: "17.00" },
                { Code: 5, Nome: 'Laranja', Valor: "30.00" }
            ]
        }
    },
```

Portanto, quando você atualiza ela com os métodos adicionar e/ou remover:

```
methods: {
      adicionar() {
          this.quantidade++
      },
      
      remover() {
          if(this.quantidade === 0) {
              this.quantidade = 0
          } else {
              this.quantidade--
          }
      }
    }
```

Você está atualizando a mesma variável que é utilizada em todos os campos.

---

> Para resolver isso, declare **uma** variável **para cada** um dos `<input></input>`.

Uma dica seria utilizar um método para adicionar e outro para remover, passando o nome da variável que deseja adicionar ou subtrair:

```
adicionar(variavel, quantidade){
   variavel += quantidade;
}

remover(variavel, quantidade){
   variavel -= quantidade;
}
```

Existem várias formas de implementar isso, na documentação original do [site](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/) você irá encontrar vários exemplos, ou pode assistir a alguns [cursos](https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/intro-to-vue-js/vue-instance) parcialmente gratuitos cabe a você selecionar o que julgar mais performático ou que tenha maior clareza, isso não vem ao caso...